# Node React Google Login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, google-authentication, passport-google-oauth

I have been learning react and node together and have been trying to implement using google auth.  I believe I have the front end side working as I can get an access token back but I can't seem to complete the authentication with the node side of it.  Here is my React code.

```
export default class GoogleLoginComponent extends Component { 

    responseGoogle(response){
        var id_token = response.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        var googlePlus = '101603157010265563225'
       console.log({accessToken: id_token});

        //axios.get('oauth',id_token)
    }

    render(){
        return(
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId="115435392551-qamvp0loln91e4d2uoat8pnki4f705o6.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        buttonText="Login"
        onSuccess={this.responseGoogle.bind(this)}
        onFailure={this.responseGoogle.bind(this)}
      />
      )
    }
}
```

This will print out the id_token successfully for me.  My issue I believe at least(but what do I know) is on the server side.  In google I set up oauth as the callback address.  Will Google make the get call to oauth or do I have to do it?  When I try and do it myself I get a whole mess of errors.  Here is the server side code.

```
var GoogleStrategy = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     "115435392551-qamvp0loln91e4d2uoat8pnki4f705o6.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    clientSecret: "_9tCI3_e-oKFwz1kFkxvRKMM",
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/oauth",
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
));

app.get( '/oauth', 
    passport.authenticate( 'google', { 
        successRedirect: 'success.html',
        failureRedirect: 'fail.html'
    })

        );
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And are you using the `passport` middleware for this ?

Comment: Is that not what passort.use is? 
At one point I tried throwing in

 app.use( passport.initialize());
app.use( passport.session()); 

because I saw it somewhere but it didn't change anything

Comment: I was asking because there is a tag for that.

Comment: Not sure I am fully following you.  I did install passport as a package and imported it into the node script to be able to call it above.

Comment: No, I was just asking because I wanted to tag your question with passport.js, as that's what this question is really about, how the built in strategies in Passport work.

Comment: ok gotcha.  Didn't realize that was it's own complete thing